# how do I consume a future from a resolved fetch request?

Tags: javascript, promise, fetch-api, coinbase-api, fluture

I am using the coinbase dev API to access assets.
To access rates data requires an access key which the API sends back from a POST request.
I am using **Flutures** and a module called [Fetch-Futures](https://github.com/theodesp/fetch-future) instead of just using the promise-based fetch API.

I haven't used Futures before. The response status is **ok(200)** but all options in the object I get back say resolved next to them ([see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQVm5.png)).

What does it mean exactly that the type of each key inside the data object is resolved?

Does this mean I should be able to use the values already or do I need an additional step before I can return my access token?

I would like a nice way to access `r.json[_value].access_token`.

JS :

```
function exchangeCodeForAccessToken(tempCode) {
  const accessTokenURL = exchangeCode.url(tempCode);

  const getAccessToken = url => {
    console.log(fetchy);
    return fetchy(url, exchangeCode.options)
      .map(r => {
        console.log(2, r.json);
        return r;
      })
      .value(console.log);
  };
```

Comment: getch-future uses "fluture" package - perhaps reading its documentation will help https://www.npmjs.com/package/fluture

Comment: I have read the documentation. Can you be specific about which part in the documentation.

Comment: the part that explains what a `fluture` returns I guess

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, Fetch-Futures wraps all values in its return object in Futures:

https://github.com/theodesp/fetch-future/blob/10af776d2653eaf75aea580b9dd2a52ae9175abd/src/index.js#L42-L59

I'm not sure what the reason for this is*, but it means you will likely have to flatten the properties you need into the outer Future, like so:

```
return fetchy(url, exchangeCode.options)

// I'm using chain instead of map, because chain flattens the Future
// And since r.json is a Future, that works out:
.chain(r => r.json)

//Now I can map, and the value will be what was inside r.json:
.map(json => json.accessToken)
```

---

<sub>* If I were you, I would probably use something other than Fetch-Futures. It seems to be somewhat outdated and will likely not work with the latest version of Fluture, and uses a questionable API design with the wrapping of the output values.</sub>

Comment: Agreed. This API makes absolutely no sense.

Comment: …and the `.chain(res => res.json())` example given in the readme doesn't match the implementation you've linked